# Length of string[] (number of elements in a string)

Tags: c++, string

I want to cout my string, everything works as it should, but when the string is shown, it immediately shows me the "example_4578.exe has stopped running" error. I have noticed that the problem is in the **i < str[32].length** part, because when I change it to i < 3, it works without any problem. How should I solve this?

```
std::string str[32];
cin >> str[1];
cout << "str[1]=" << str[1] << endl;

cin >> str[2];
cout << "str[2]=" << str[2] << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < str[32].length; i++)
{
    cout << str[i];
}
```

**EDIT 1.**
I've made a huge mistake. I actually want to find the "number" of elements/words in "str". In my example, I have only designed two cins. But I actually want to design a "for" loop later on, so that the user can input as many words as he wants, so if he inputs 4 words, I want that code to return those number of words to me. How should I do this? In other words, how can I find out how many elements are in "**str**"?

Comment: maybe .length() as its a function or just use i<32 if you know it will be a constant

Comment: When you declare an array as `[32]`, valid indicies are `[0]` to `[31]`.  Therefore, referring to `str[32]` is ***invalid***.

Comment: Re your edit: the array always contains 32 strings, some of which may be empty. You need to keep track of the number of strings yourself, or look into `std::vector`.

Comment: It sounds like you want a dynamic array, [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), not a fixed size array. Add strings to it with the `push_back()` member function, and get the number of strings with `size()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str[32].length` is not what you think.

I guess you meant somthing like: *length of a 32-elements array*. Right?

What you've written is *pointer to funciton `length` of 33rd element of array*.

This is because the types are:

```
std::string str[32]; // `str` is 32-element array of `std::strings`
str[32]; // `std::string` taken from 33rd position in array `str` (arrays' indexing starts at 0)
```

`std::string` has a member function named `size_t std::string::length()`. When referenced by name, you get its address.

To achieve what you wanted, you'd need to write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    cout << str[i];
}
```

Unfortunately, plain arrays don't have `length` (or anything similar) built in. So, you'd either need to use a constant, or (better) use a container, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to enter as many lines as s/he wants, don't use static-sized arrays. If you do, you'll have a problem when the user wants to enter 33rd element. As you're using C++, use standard containers, such as `std::vector` or `std::list`.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of things:

1. C++ is 0-indexed. What this means is that `std::string str[32]` has indices that go from 0 to 31, and `str[32]` should not be accessed. This will cause a crash.
2. `str[31].length()` (which is presumably what you wanted) is the length of the last string, not the length of the array. The length of the array is 32, and your loop should read `for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)`.

Comment: Technically `str[32]` is guaranteed to exists. It's just that accessing that memory location is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Since the OP is apparently new to C++, I didn't want to needlessly complicate the answer with the existence of one-past-the-end pointers and such.

Comment: Well, precisely because OP is new to C++, telling him lies is not a great idea. I know what you meant, but I'm not sure OP does. That's why "accessing an element out of the bounds of the array is bad" seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Fair enough. I've changed `does not exist` to `should not be accessed`.

Comment: @gejak That should probably be a separated question.

Comment: @gejak Yeah, your current question has already been answered. Changing the body that drastically would invalidate every answer up until now.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are accessing an element (number 32) that is out of the bounds (0 - 31). To solve this problem and not repeat it again in the future use a range-`for` loop:

```
std::string str[32];
for (auto s : str)
    std::cout << s;
```